# How do I stop an error when I have multiple roots supplied via MySQL in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been trying to produce a family tree using D3.js to display MySQL data directly to a webpage, currently my code is as follows :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
      <style>
        * {
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        path {
          fill: none;
          stroke: silver;
          stroke-width: 2px;
        }
        
        rect {
          width: 80px;
          height: 40px;
          fill: #ffffff;
          stroke: silver;
          stroke-width: 2px;
        }
        
        text {
          dominant-baseline: middle;
          text-anchor: middle;
        }
        
        .global-container {
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
        }
        
        .svg-container {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
        }
        
        .tree-controls {
          position: absolute;
          float: right;
          top: 0px;
          right: 0px;
        }
        
        .tree-controls button{
          float: right;
          padding: 5px;
          border: unset;
          background-color: #7de37f;
          color: #ffffff;
          margin: 2.5px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .tree-controls button:hover{
          background-color: #61b062;
        }
        
        .tree-controls button i{
          padding-right: 5px;
        }
        
        .hide {
          display: none;
        }
        
      </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="center()">
    <div class="tree-controls">
        <button onclick="zoomIn()"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i>| Zoom In</button></br>
        <button onclick="zoomOut()"><i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i>| Zoom Out</button></br>
        <button onclick="resetZoom()"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i>| Reset Zoom</button></br>
        <button onclick="center()"><i class="fas fa-crosshairs"></i>| Center</button>
    </div>
    <div class="global-container">
        
    </div>
      
      <?php

    include_once 'config/logconfig.php';

    $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    $queryall = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `id`,`pid`,`ppid`,`firstname` FROM product_data");

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryall)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }

    $mysqloutput = json_encode($rows);

    echo $mysqloutput;

    ?>

    <script>

    var data = <?php echo $mysqloutput?>;

    console.log(data);

    var svg = d3
        .select("div.global-container")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "svg-container")
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "table-boundaries");
                
    var dataStructure = d3
        .stratify()
        .id(function(d){return d.id;})
        .parentId(function(d){return d.pid;})
        (data);
                            
    var treeStructure = d3
        .tree()
        .size([1000,350]);
                            
    var information = treeStructure(dataStructure);

    var connections = svg
        .append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(information.links());

    connections
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", function(d){
            return "M" + (d.source.x-20) + "," + d.source.y + " v 50 H" + d.target.x + " V" + d.target.y;
        })
        .attr("class", "connections");

    var rectangles = svg
        .append("g")
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(information.descendants());
        
    rectangles
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d){return d.x-60;})
        .attr("y", function(d){return d.y-20;})
        .attr("class", "rectangles");
        
    var spouseRectangles = svg
        .append("g")
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(information.descendants());
        
    spouseRectangles
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d){return d.x+60;})
        .attr("y", function(d){return d.y-20;})
        .classed("hide", function(d){
            if(d.data.ppid == null)
                return true;
                    else
                return false;
        });
        
    var names = svg
        .append("g")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(information.descendants());
        
    names
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d){return d.data.firstname;})
        .attr("x", function(d){return d.x-20;})
        .attr("y", function(d){return d.y;})
        .attr("class", "names");
        
    let zoom = d3
        .zoom()
        .scaleExtent([0.25, 10])
        .on("zoom", handleZoom);

    function initZoom() {d3
        .select("svg")
        .call(zoom);
    }

    function handleZoom(e) {d3
        .select("svg g")
        .attr("transform", e.transform);
    }

    function zoomIn() {d3
        .select("svg")
        .transition()
        .call(zoom.scaleBy, 2);
    }

    function zoomOut() {d3
        .select("svg")
        .transition()
        .call(zoom.scaleBy, 0.5);
    }

    function resetZoom() {d3
        .select("svg")
        .transition()
        .call(zoom.scaleTo, 1);
    }

    function center() {d3
        .select("svg")
        .transition()
        .call(zoom.translateTo, 0.5 * 330, 0.5 * 340);
    }

    initZoom();
    update();
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am supplying D3.js the below JSON :

```
[{"id":"1","pid":null,"ppid":null,"firstname":"Liam"},{"id":"2","pid":"1","ppid":null,"firstname":"Monster"},{"id":"3","pid":"1","ppid":null,"firstname":"Cherry"},{"id":"5","pid":"3","ppid":null,"firstname":"Chandler"},{"id":"6","pid":"3","ppid":null,"firstname":"Fan"},{"id":"7","pid":"1","ppid":null,"firstname":"Derek"},{"id":"8","pid":"1","ppid":null,"firstname":"Sarah"},{"id":"9","pid":"2","ppid":null,"firstname":"Freyah"},{"id":"14","pid":null,"ppid":"2","firstname":"Miss"}]
```

and I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: multiple roots
> at e (d3.v7.min.js:2)
> at (index):105

I have tried changing the data type the spouseRectangles takes but cannot figure out why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

You have two objects with no `parentId`, the first one and the last one (both have `pid: null`). That said, the error message is properly expected: you can have only one root node (a node without parent).

Assuming the last object has a typo and the `pid` and `ppid` properties are swapped, you have a proper hierarchy with **one** root only:

```js
const data = [{
  "id": "1",
  "pid": null,
  "ppid": null,
  "firstname": "Liam"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "pid": "1",
  "ppid": null,
  "firstname": "Monster"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "pid": "1",
  "ppid": null,
  "firstname": "Cherry"
}, {
  "id": "5",
  "pid": "3",
  "ppid": null,
  "firstname": "Chandler"
}, {
  "id": "6",
  "pid": "3",
  "ppid": null,
  "firstname": "Fan"
}, {
  "id": "7",
  "pid": "1",
  "ppid": null,
  "firstname": "Derek"
}, {
  "id": "8",
  "pid": "1",
  "ppid": null,
  "firstname": "Sarah"
}, {
  "id": "9",
  "pid": "2",
  "ppid": null,
  "firstname": "Freyah"
}, {
  "id": "14",
  "pid": "2",
  "ppid": null,
  "firstname": "Miss"
}];

const dataStructure = d3
  .stratify()
  .id(function(d) {
    return d.id;
  })
  .parentId(function(d) {
    return d.pid;
  })
  (data);

console.log(dataStructure)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, if that's not a typo and you really have a data structure with two root nodes, there's no idiomatic D3 solution for you, since D3 hierarchy explicitly forbids multiple root nodes. In that case, you'll have to write your own JavaScript or tweak the D3 source.

Comment: I would like the parents to have spouses as well, this includes a spouse for the first contact. Does this count as a second root node?